# Oracle SQL - how to count using PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

I am trying to transpose some rows into columns using PIVOT, but I am stuck as I need to use multiple counts within one another.

I only got this far:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT id, city, main_type, p_type 
    FROM table.table_name
)  sourcetable
PIVOT 
    (COUNT(id) FOR main_type IN ('Other', 'Private', 'Public')
)
ORDER BY city;
```

However, I have between 1 and 4 distinct p_type values for each main_type and I would like to count each city only once.
This means for each main_type, there need to be 4 "sub-counts" (for lack of a better word) for each p_type. This is how the data looks after the above query:

```
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
| City  |P_type |Other |Public|Private|
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|NYC    |Small  |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|NYC    |Medium |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|NYC    |Large  |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|Dallas |Small  |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|Dallas |Large  |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|Miami  |Small  |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|Miami  |Medium |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|Miami  |Large  |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
|Miami  |XL     |  11  |   15 | 10    |
|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
```

```
I would like it to look like this:
|-------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|.......
| City  |Other/Small |Other/Small |Other/Medium |Public/Small|......
|-------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|
|NYC    |14          |  11        |   15        | 10         |
|-------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|
|Dallas |10          |  11        |   15        | 10         |
|-------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|
|Miami  |15          |  11        |   15        | 10         |
|-------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|
```

Is there even a way to do this in SQL?

P.S. My knowledge of SQL is elementary so please bear with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using conditional aggregation?

```
select City, P_type,
       sum(case when main_type = 'Other' then 1 else 0 end) as other,
       sum(case when main_type = 'Public' then 1 else 0 end) as Public,
       sum(case when main_type = 'Private' then 1 else 0 end) as Private
from table.table_name
where city, p_type
group by City, P_Type;
```

EDIT:

You can add more columns like this:

```
select City,
       sum(case when p_type = 'Small' and main_type = 'Other' then 1 else 0 end) as small_other,
       sum(case when p_type = 'Small' and main_type = 'Public' then 1 else 0 end) as small_Public,
       sum(case when p_type = 'Small' and main_type = 'Private' then 1 else 0 end) as small_Private,
       sum(case when p_type = 'Medium' and main_type = 'Other' then 1 else 0 end) as medium_other,
       . . . 
from table.table_name
where city, p_type
group by City;
```

Comment: This alone does not help me count all cities once. For each main_type I need to count the value for each p_type, eg. for NYC count separately Public with small, Public with medium, etc. until I have exhausted all values. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AnnaB . . . You have a table in the question that looks like the results you want  You have no table in the question that shows all the values pivoted across columns, so I think the question is unclear.  In any case, I edited the answer to show you how to generalize to having more columns.

Comment: @Gordon...the table I posted was the result after using pivot. I have edited my initial post to make it clear. Your edit helps a lot. I believe I am now getting the desired result and it is some Sql that is not beyond my level :D .

Answer (score 0):

There are some static pivoting methods such as using `PIVOT` Clause, or `Conditional Aggregation`, in which all the resulting pivoted columns should be specified explicitly, while there's no direct dynamic method through using **SQL** only.

`SYS_REFCURSOR` within a stored function(eg. **PL/SQL** used instead of using SQL directly) might be used as an alternative in order to get dynamically generated result set(eg. **Dynamic Pivot**) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Cities_RS RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||main_type||''' AS "'||LOWER(main_type)||'"' , ',' ) 
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY 1 ) --# "ORDER BY" clause is required
    INTO v_str
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT main_type  
             FROM cities ); 

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT *
     FROM (
           SELECT id, city, main_type, p_type 
             FROM cities
          )
    PIVOT
    (
     COUNT(id) FOR main_type IN ( '|| v_str ||' )
    )
    ORDER BY city';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

Then run the below code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Cities_RS;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to see the expected result set.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91eccd426892b17b6aa6077830ba1de0)</kbd>